# Keras LSTM, expected 3 but got array with shape []

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, named-entity-extraction

I am trying to find out label associated with word from annotated text. I am using a `bidirectional LSTM`. I have `X_train` which is having shape **(1676, 39)** and `Y_train` with the same shape **(1676, 39)**.

```
input = Input(shape=(sequence_length,))
model = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=20,
              input_length=sequence_length, mask_zero=True)(input)
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,
                       recurrent_dropout=0.1))(model)
out_model = TimeDistributed(Dense(50, activation="softmax"))(model) 
model = Model(input, out_model)
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss= "categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32, epochs= 10,
                validation_split=0.1)
```

While executing this, I am getting error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_5 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1676, 39).
```

I am not able to find out how to feed proper dimension which is needed by the Keras LSTM model.

Comment: I don't understand your data with respect to your model. What are the values of sequence_length and n_words. Could you add the output of model.summary()?
But in any case your output will have size 50 (size of your last layer).

Answer (score 0):

In the `LSTM` you set `return_sequences=True`, as a result, the outputs of the layer is a Tensor with shape of [**batch_size** * **39** * **50**]. Then you pass this Tensor to [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) layer. `TimeDistributed` apply Dense layer on the each time stamp. The outputs of the layer, again is [**batch_size** * **39** * **50**]. As you see, you pass 3 dimension Tensor for prediction, while your ground truth is 2 dimension (1676, 39).

*How to **fix** the issue?*

1) Remove `return_sequences=True` from LSTM args.

2) Remove `TimeDistributed` layer and apply Dense layer directly.

```
inps = keras.layers.Input(shape=(39,))
embedding = keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 16)(inps)
rnn = keras.layers.LSTM(50)(embedding)
dense = keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="softmax")(rnn)
prediction = keras.layers.Dense(39, activation='softmax')(dense)
```